# Get X,Y coordinates from Angle & Distance ( Incorrect values using Math.cos() & Math.sin() )

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates

I've read all accepted answers on this topic and repeated exactly the logic used in them but my results seem to be skewed and 'random'.

I have correctly collected the X,Y and degrees from the center object as shown here:

```
console.log('deg' + degrees + ' - ' + 'x' + parseInt(x) + ', y' + parseInt(y));
```

[image]
**Note:** The X,Y grid spans much further out of the viewport that is shown. Technically the grid is unlimited in size. We are in our own specific X,Y coordinate in this grid space.

Now I want to calculate an X,Y coordinate that is 1000 pixels away from the click position. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The logic I found elsewhere should be as simple as such:

```
x = 1000 * Math.cos(degrees);
y = 1000 * Math.sin(degrees);
console.log('deg' + degrees + ' - ' + 'x' + parseInt(x) + ', y' + parseInt(y));
```

The result is as such:

[image]

**The issue:** Clearly in the image above, the X,Y coordinates are way off to what I should be expecting. They are much too low and change too often to random numbers.

The grid for this layout is as shown below:

[image]

**Note:** The X axis goes positive to the left. Is this the underlying issue or is it my original logic that is wrong?

Thank you for considering my question

---

I've tried the suggested code. Here are my results.

Result from @MBo's *now old* answer:

```
new_x = 1000 * Math.cos(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
new_y = 1000 * Math.sin(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
```

[image]

The results look a lot cleaner and less 'random' however the end X,Y go in the incorrect direction and distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > and change too often

Trigonometric functions work [with radians](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) rather than degrees, so calculate arguments like this:

```
 Math.cos(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
 Math.sin(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
```

To make rotation around some point, add these values to its coordinates

```
 x = center_object_x + Math.cos(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
 y = center_object_y + Math.sin(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
```

Comment: The results look a lot cleaner but the end X,Y seem to be incorrect. I've updated my question with my test using your code. Do you mind checking that I have done it correctly? Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: `new_x = 1000 * Math.cos(degrees * Math.PI / 180);` calculates x-shift from zero point. Result -683,-729 looks quite correct for 226 degrees (angle in the 3-rd quadrant gives negative sin and cos). Perhaps you need to add some base point (center of rotation)?  `screen_x = center_object_x + 1000 * Math.cos(degrees * Math.PI / 180);` c

Comment: Ah, yes I think you are right! I need to add the X,Y position of my object. Let me just test this..!

Comment: My mistake was to look at pure Mathematics answers and put that straight into my code yet, as you stated, `Math.cos() & Math.sin()` don't use degrees which I should have looked up. Thank you very much for your answer and help here, really appreciate it.