# Find position when given an angle and distance

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I would like to use javascript to locate the x and y coordinate of any point on a Cartesian coordinate system when given an angle between 0 and 2pi and the distance from the origin.

Is there simpler way of writing this function? (in my program angles are measured clockwise from (1,0))

```
function findPosition(distance, angle){
    let dx, dy;
    if (angle >= 0 && angle <= Math.PI/2){
        dx = distance * Math.cos(angle);
        dy = distance * Math.sin(angle);
    } else if (angle > Math.PI/2 && angle <= Math.PI){
        dx = -distance * Math.cos(angle);
        dy = distance * Math.sin(angle);
    } else if (angle > Math.PI && angle <= 3 * Math.PI / 2){
        dx = -distance * Math.cos(angle);
        dy = -distance * Math.sin(angle);
    } else if (angle > 3* Math.PI/2 && angle <= 2 * Math.PI){
        dx = distance * Math.cos(angle);
        dy = -distance * Math.sin(angle);
    } else {
        console.log("Error: Bad angle");
    }
    return [dx , dy]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get X,Y coordinates from Angle & Distance ( Incorrect values using Math.cos() & Math.sin() )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53879165/get-x-y-coordinates-from-angle-distance-incorrect-values-using-math-cos)

Comment: or [Figure out point Y by angle and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456783/javascript-figure-out-point-y-by-angle-and-distance) or [Calculating cordanates with angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955714/calculating-cordanates-with-angles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findPosition(distance, angle) {
  const dx = distance * Math.cos(angle);
  const dy = distance * Math.sin(angle);
  return [dx, dy];
}
```

If your angle is measured clockwise from (1,0), you can modify the function call like this:

```
const angle = 2 * Math.PI - desiredAngle;
const position = findPosition(distance, angle);
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling I was making that more complicated than necessary.

Comment: >> If your angle is measured clockwise,    Or you could do -> `const dy = -distance * Math.sin(angle); `